# iphone: make view transparent but subviews non transparent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a Custom UIViewController named A and i want to add its view to another controllers (named B) view as subview. A's view contain two buttons as subviews. I want to make A's view transparent but the buttons in it nontransparent. I want to know is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

As of I noticed,

> If a view is set a opacity/alpha value, all its subviews will be applied with that opacity/alpha value.

Try setting the views background color to `[UIColor clearColor]`

Answer (score 1):

```
viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[viewA addSubview:button1];
[viewA addSubview:button2];
```