# Clear background-color on UIView with drawn content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicolor

Inside my FirstView, I put a second view which I wanted to use for drawn content. The drawing works fine, but the problem is that the background of that second view is black. I tried to set the background color of the view to clear color using:

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

but it's still black.

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface CustomView ()

@end

@implementation CustomView


 -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {

        UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

        aPath.lineWidth = 15;

        //set the stoke color
        [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];

        // Set the starting point of the shape.
        [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 0.0)];

        // Draw the lines.
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 40.0)];
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(160, 140)];
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0, 140)];
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 40.0)];
        [aPath closePath];

        //draw the path
        [aPath stroke];
    }





@end
```

Comment: are you setting both views to `[UIColor clearColor]`? I think you need to based upon this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633468/iphone-make-view-transparent-but-subviews-non-transparent

Comment: ok it works now. I made a dumb mistake. I had another function which controlled the backgroundColor of the first view. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you setting both views to [UIColor clearColor]? I think you need to based upon this: [iphone: make view transparent but subviews non transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633468/iphone-make-view-transparent-but-subviews-non-transparent)